# Why documentdb query returns data which is undefined or empty value?

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-hub

I am using documentdb & running query of documentdb. my sample query is looks like:

```
studentQuery = {
        query: 'SELECT * FROM root r WHERE (r.userid=@userid OR r.code=@code) AND r.collectionName="students"',
        parameters: [{
            name: '@userid',
            value: userid
        }, {
            name: '@code',
            value: code
        }]
    };
```

Now problem is that if I am passing only userid="piyush123" and code= "", then it is returning me all those records which has code="" empty value, if code is undefined though it returns all those documents which doesn't contain code.

shortly I don't want those records which  has null or empty string or undefined value, I can resolve it by `IS_DEFINED, IS_NULL, NOT IS_NULL` kind of keywords, but I don't want to use it in all queries 'cause its making my query structure to complex, so I want to apply it at once place so I should not bother about all kind of check everywhere which can reduce my efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a UDF that wraps all cases - empty string, nulls, and undefined and call that within query.

1. Register a `IsMissing` UDF like the following using [CreateUserDefinedFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createuserdefinedfunctionasync.aspx)
2. Use within a query by name. For example, `SELECT * FROM c WHERE udf.IsMissing(c.code) AND ...`

Here's a simple implementation of IsMissing:

```
function isMissing(doc, prop) {
  if (typeof doc[prop] === "undefined") {
    return true;
  } 

  if (doc[prop] === "" || doc[prop] === null) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: How to write or inject UDF function in query & how to use it? If you can suggest it would be appreciable.